# Ошибка Symfony Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: json ~~ unknown

Tags: php, symfony

При изучении Symfony решил поиграться с ролями. Мне нужно достать всех юзеров у которых роль 'ROLE_MODERATOR'

В репозитории создал следующий метод

```
public function getModerators()
{
    $role = 'ROLE_MODERATOR';

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->select('u')
        ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles')
        ->setParameter('roles', '%"'.$role.'"%');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

В итоге получаю ошибку

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: json ~~ unknown HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

БД использую Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете делать поиск по json полю в базе с обычным like.

Либо надо подключить библиотеку, которая позволят искать в json либо написать свой обработчик, либо что-то подобное этому (обработку параметра role напишите сами)

```
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM user where jsonb_exists(roles, '{$role}'";

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $ids = $stmt->executeQuery()->fetchFirstColumn();

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.id IN (:ids)')
            ->setParameter('ids', $ids)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Здесь выполняется поиск по-нативному sql и получаете id найденных пользователей, затем строится запрос orm, чтобы достать уже объекты User